# Getting from a long list of strings to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pricelist in pdf format which I have imported into a list. The format is such that my list looks as in the sample below.

```
sample = ['model description price model description price 39A Bolt 25.00 21B valve 322.40 AB3003 Engine  5000\n20B Nut 1.50 25B LockNut 3.50',
          'model description price  model description price 44C Spanner 100.00 01BC Pipe 3.10 ZZ010  Blade  345.44\n33J Tube 8.89 377GH CAM 44.20']
```

For each element of the list 'model description price ' always repeats once, and then is followed by the actual data. For each element of the list there are up to circa 20 sequences of model/description/price of the actual data.

What I am trying to get to is a simple Pandas DataFrame that appears as follows:

```
data={'model':['39A','21B','AB3003','20B','25B','44C','01BC','ZZ010','33J','377GH'], 
      'description': ['Bolt', 'valve', 'engine','nut','locknut', 'spanner','pipe','blade','tube','cam'],
     'price': [25.00,322.40,5000,1.50,3.50,100.00,3.10,345.44,8.89,44.20]}
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: Desired Outcome]

I have tried the following to at least get each element of the original list separated into nested list

```
sample2 = [i.split(' ') for i in sample]
pd.DataFrame(sample2)
```

but the resultant looks nothing like the DataFrame I am looking for.

Could anyone help me out please?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I wrote that will work for the sample you have provided:

```
import re, pdb
import pandas as pd
sample = ['model description price model description price 39A Bolt 25.00 21B valve 322.40 AB3003 Engine  5000\n20B Nut 1.50 25B LockNut 3.50',
          'model description price  model description price 44C Spanner 100.00 01BC Pipe 3.10 ZZ010  Blade  345.44\n33J Tube 8.89 377GH CAM 44.20']

DF_list = []

#remove 'model description price'
remove_str = lambda sub_str, some_str: re.sub(r'\b' + sub_str + r'\b', '', some_str)
sample = [remove_str('model description price', x).strip() for x in sample]

#remove newline
sample = [re.split(r'[\n\t]', line) for line in sample]
sample = [item for sublist in sample for item in sublist]


#parse into data frame
for data_string in sample:
  data_list = data_string.split(' ')
  data_list = [x for x in data_list if x != '']
  small_lists = [data_list[x:x+3] for x in range(0, len(data_list), 3)]
  [DF_list.append(x) for x in small_lists]

DF = pd.DataFrame(DF_list)
```